# MapQuest for iOS. MQMapKit - MQMapView - MQRoute custom annotation view (image)

Tags: ios, mapquest

Does there exist a way for customizing MQRoute look? Especially I'm interested in customizing annotations that represent the route start and end points.

As a result of calling `[MQRoute getRouteWithStartCoordinate:endCoordinate:]` the map displays orange route line and two purple balloons that indicate start and end points. How can I replace images of these balloons? How can I change line color, style?

Answer (score 0):

So far I found the next answer regarding MQRoute customization:

> To create custom routes you can call the Directions Web Service
>   directly and create overlays and markers as needed. The wrapper that
>   creates the route for you does a basic route, but does not handle
>   customization well.